# "tsc.exe" exited with code 255

Tags: typescript, msbuild, typescript2.0

I'm trying to build my application using **Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.0-beta** on my CIS server (TeamCity) and it fails with next error:

> Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.0-beta\tools\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(223, 5): error MSB6006: "tsc.exe" exited with code 255

I have few tsconfig.json configurations and it fails on first of it.

Also I can build application on local PC without any errors. I'm using VS 2015 Pro with TS2.0-beta installed.

What could be the reason and how could it be fixed?
And what code 255 actually mean (could not find any explanation on this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in new verion **Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.2-rc**